# VS code won't open a window when i run my code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Earlier today everything was working perfectly fine. But at some point, the "run" function stoped working.

When I click on run, nothing happens. Not even an empty terminal or an error message. Just nothing.
If I click on "create a new terminal" I do get a terminal. But this is without my code.

I've made a new file and the only code in there is: print("Hello world"), and even this doesn't work.

I haven't changed any settings, and tried reinstalling VS code multiple times but nothing works. I couldn't find anything online about this either. I also checked my python version and the path within VS code, but for as far as I can see everything is as it should be.

Is there someone here who knows how to fix this?

Comment: Please do not tag Visual Studio for issues with VS Code.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your "run" command in GUI of Ctrl+Shift+P panel